# Adding items from View to an array (backbone.js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have a parent view `ProductListView` containing multiple child views `ProductView` in a multi-step wizard. When a user click on a `ProductView`, its model's id should be stored somewhere (possibly in an array) so that it can be sent back to the server side for processing.

**Problem:** Where should I store the `id` of the `ProductView` that has been clicked by the user? I tried storing it in its parent view `ProductListView` but cannot seem to access the array `selectedProducts` in the parent view from the child view `ProductView`.

Is this the correct approach? How should this be done?

**Model**

```
ProductCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Product,
    url: '/wizard'
});
```

**Parent View**

```
ProductListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#photo_list',

    selectedProducts: {},  // STORING SELECTED PRODUCTS IN THIS ARRAY

    initialize: function() {
        this.collection.bind('reset', this.render, this);
    },

    render: function() {
        this.collection.each(function(product, index){
            $(this.el).append(new ProductView({ model: product }).render().el);
        }, this);
        return this;
    }
});
```

**Child View**

```
ProductView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagname: 'div',
    className: 'photo_box',

    events: {
        'click': 'toggleSelection'
    },

    template: _.template($('#tpl-PhotoListItemView').html()),

    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template( this.model.toJSON() ));
        return this;
    },

    // ADDS ITS MODEL'S ID TO ARRAY
    toggleSelection: function() {
        this.parent.selectedProducts.push(this.model.id);
        console.log(this.parent.selectedProducts);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think `parent` is a property of a backbone `View` type, and you haven't defined it, so there's no way this line is going to work:

```
this.parent.selectedProducts.push(this.model.id);
```

It seems like the correct approach would be to add a `selected` property to the `Product` model; toggle that property in the click handler.  Then, when it's time to submit to the server, collect the IDs by filtering the Products collection for selected items (underscore.js included with Backbone makes this easy).

Comment: I would also take @dbaseman's approach and have each model have a `selected` attribute. Then at the end you just do `collection.filter(function(product){return product.selected === true;})` to get an array of selected products models. You can easily `pluck()` the ids if you want too. But Backbone being as it is, your way of pushing an array is also not incorrect. Just pass in a reference of your parent view to you child. `var childView = new ProductView({'parent': parentView});` and you can access your parentView array.

Answer (score 1):

Why not try to keep selected information, directly in model. So, you will be easily tracking change state of selected using events, and use that information on further wizard steps?

```
toggleSelection: function () {
    this.model.set({ selected: true });
}
```